# Double orthogonal complement of a finite module

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, modules

Crossposted from [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64016/periodicity-of-the-nullspace-of-a-module) since I'm not getting any answer.

Let $W$ be the finite $\mathbb{Z}$-module obtained from $\mathbb{Z}_q^n$ with addition componentwise where $\mathbb{Z}_q$ is the integers mod $q$. Let $V$ be a submodule of $W$. Let $V^{\perp} = \{w \in W \, : \, \forall v \in V,\, v \cdot w = 0 \}$ where "$\cdot$" is the dot product. Is it true that ${(V^{\perp})}^{\perp} = V$ for all $q \geq 2$? If not, when is it the case?

Comment: Not that it's my business, but why Paul here and Thomas there?

Comment: Because my full name is Paul Thomas. Does it change anything?

Comment: Be careful with your notation. I think it's safe to say most algebraists and algebraic topologists read $\mathbb{Z}_q$ as the $q$-adic numbers, not as $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$. Because not everyone adopts this notation, I generally explicitly define my terms. Which do you mean?

Comment: @David: I agree with your injunction in general -- at least, when I write $\mathbb{Z}_q$ I mean the $q$-adic integers (although I know some algebraic topologists who take the other convention).  But in this case the OP says he wants a "finite $\mathbb{Z}$-modules" which seems to imply that $\mathbb{Z}_q = \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$.  Anyway, he also doesn't say what kind of integer $q$ is -- e.g., is it necessarily prime?  In view of my answer below, that's a more serious question...

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the comments, I've specified my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is yes. The easiest way for me is to appeal to character theory. If $\zeta$ is
a complex $q$-th root of 1 then the map from $\mathbb{Z}_q^n$ to $\mathbb{C}$ given by
$$
 x \mapsto \zeta^{a^Tx},\qquad (a\in\mathbb{Z}_q^n)
$$
is a character of the abelian group $W=\mathbb{Z}_q^n$. The set of characters obtained as
$a$ varies over the elements of $W$ is the character group $W^*$ of $W$. 
If $V$ is a subgroup of $W$, then $V^\perp=V^*$ is isomorphic to the subgroup $(W/V)^*$ 
of $W^*$.

A convenient source for the relevant character theory is from our own KConrad:  `http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/` (under characters of finite abelian groups).

Comment: Are you perhaps mixing up inner products with values in $\mathbb{C}$ with inner products with values in $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$?  Or am I the one who is confused??

Comment: 
I think Chris is right. He's talking about inner product with values in $Z/qZ$ which is identified with the group of $q$-roots of unity in $C^\ast$. Let me reformulate its proof. Letting G be the abelian group Z_q^n, then the scalar product of the question can be seen as a perfect pairing $G \times G \rightarrow C^\ast$ that identifies
$G$ with its dual group in the sense of character theory. The question becomes: for a finite abelian group $G$, and a subgroup $V$, is $(V^\bot)^\bot=V$ and the answer is yes by standard theory of duality of abelian groups.


Comment: Note that of course this is false if $Z/qZ$ is replaced by $Z$ (example $G=Z, V=2Z$). This is an example among others where the non-domain $Z/qZ$ behave in a more familiar way (that is more like a field) that the simplest non-field domain, namely $Z$. Here is another example with the same flavor: if a submodule of $(Z/qZ)^n$ is free, then it is direct summand. What make the things work is the (local) Artinian nature of the ring $Z/qZ$

Comment: By the way, how do you do the nice blackboard Z and C?



Comment: @Joël: Thanks, I think I understand it now.  BTW, you can use latex in the comments by enclosing it with single dollar signs as usual.


Comment: Test : $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{C}$. Thanks.


Comment: Your answer seems interesting. I've been reading the notes from KConrad, but I don't see how you are getting $V^{\perp} = V^*$.

Comment: @Paul: I should have used $\equiv$, not $=$. The point is that if $a\in V^\perp$ then $V$ lies in the kernel of the character
associated to $a$. Note that you would be able to prove what you
need without introducing characters, by working with matrix with
entries $\zeta^{a^Tb}$.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this answer?

Comment: It's very easy to see that the matrix $H$ given by $H_{a,b}=\zeta^{a^Tb}$ satisfies $H^*H=|V|I$, and I think everything follows from that. But to answer you question, I do not have a reference.

Answer (score 4):

Your question does not specify what $q$ is.  But if $q$ is an odd prime -- so that you are talking about quadratic spaces over the field $\mathbb{F}_q$ of odd characteristic -- then the answer is **yes**.

In this case your inner product $\cdot$ is the bilinear form associated to the quadratic form $q(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2$.  This quadratic form is nondegenerate, so the result you want is Proposition 7 in [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/quadraticforms.pdf).  (They are nothing so special: any sufficiently basic text on quadratic forms will contain this material.)

I am not really used to thinking about quadratic forms either in characteristic $2$ or over rings which are not domains, so if you're really interested in the case of $q$ not necessarily an odd prime, please say so, so that someone else can give a more complete answer.  (But I will guess that the result is also true when $q$ is an odd prime power, for instance.)

Comment: Yes, I recall learning this in a course I took on quadratic forms years ago. I don't think it works for composite $q$, but I can't be sure.