# Orthogonal subgroups of dual group

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory

This question arises from [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75262/double-orthogonal-complement-of-a-module).

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$. Let $\widehat{G}$ be group of all characters of $G$ and let $H^\perp = \{\chi \in \widehat{G}  :  \chi = 1 \text{ on } H\}$. Does anyone know a good reference proving the identity $(H^\perp)^\perp = H$?

I'm interested in a reference (instead of a proof) because I only need to use this fact in a non representation theory paper and won't have the space needed to introduce and prove what is needed.

Comment: Could you perhaps move the short proof to an appendix?

Comment: (you just need to set up the definitions, and then observe that the canonical map from $H$ into $(H^\perp)^\perp$ is injective; finiteness then implies surjectivity.

Comment: @Yemon Choi: I guess it could be an option. It's a theoretical computer science paper, so I thought I could avoid doing so because it'd be standard in representation theory and somewhere in some well known textbook.

Answer (score 5):

Lemma 2.1.3 in Rudin's [Fourier Analysis on Groups](http://books.google.ca/books?id=WlzLFUo0VzYC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA36#v=onepage&q&f=false) does this for locally compact abelian $G$ and closed $H \leq G$. This might not the best reference (may be a bit too general for a CS readership?), but it was the first one to pop into my head.

Answer (score 4):

It is Proposition 3.4 in the [book](http://books.google.de/books?id=qea_OXafBFoC&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=washington+cyclotomic+fields+corollary+3.2&source=bl&ots=z32Y3Nnzxl&sig=evKKGJ08bkGXat2tJp4Wp7a9_CY&hl=de&sa=X&ei=U4ZLT-y0MqSo4gTPt5DqAw&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) "Washington: Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields".

Answer (score 3):

There are very pedagogical proofs in  [[1]](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0411037) section 3.5 and in [[2]](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4867) section 6.1. In both references, the most typical properties of orthogonal subgroups of **finite-abelian** groups are proven, including the one you are looking for. I have read both texts and used both for preparing seminars, and I find the exposition quite clear. I have cited both of these references in [one of my papers](http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.3637): I think the first of them [[1]](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0411037) has never appeared in a Journal, but it is quite a trusted paper in my field (quantum computation), so you could cite the arXiv; the second reference [[2]](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4867) has recently been published in QIC Vol. 13. No.11&12,  1007 (2013).

In fact, this property is one of many consequences of the Pontryagin-Van Kampen duality, and holds for all **locally compact Abelian groups** (finite Abelian groups are a particular case of those; the integers, the real numbers, the torus are also locally compact Abelian; see also this **[related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/89664/finite-abelian-yet-fugitive-orthogonal-subgroups)** of mine in MathOverflow). If you would like to see a proof of your statement in the more general case, I recommend you to take a look at the online notes of the course *[Introduction to Topological Groups](http://users.dimi.uniud.it/~dikran.dikranjan/ITG.pdf)*, by Dikran Dikranjan, University of Udine. The relevant sections for you are:

- Section 11 *Pontryagin-van Kampen duality*, in particular 11.4.;
- the *annihilator* $A_{\widehat{G}}(H)$, defined at the beginning of section 11.4.2, is precisely the subgroup of the characters of $G$ that you are looking at;
- theorem 11.5.4. proves your statement.

As far as I know, Dikranjan's notes have never been published; still, they are (in my opinion) a very useful resource. Some parts of them (but sadly not the ones you need) have appeared in *An elementary approach to Haar integration and Pontryagin duality in locally compact abelian groups*, Dikranjan and Stoyanov, Topology and its Applications, Vol. 158, no. 15, 2011 Elsevier Science.